# Javascript performance hit for returning a function from a self-executing function?

Tags: javascript, performance, scope

In firefox there seems to be a big performance difference between the following two functions:

```
var n1 = 12;

var add1 = function(n2){
    return n1 + n2;
}

var add2 = (function(){
    return function(n2){
            return n1 + n2;
    }
})();
```

I thought this must be down to the introduction of another level of scope, so created a third example with the variable cached one level up.
But this shows an even greater reduction (80%!)

```
var add3 = (function(){
    var cn1 = n1;
    return function(n2){
            return cn1 + n2;
    }
})();
```

I would have thought that the closure here would close the performance gap, not enlarge it. Does anybody have an idea what is going on here?

jsPerf test page: http://jsperf.com/variable-scope-speed

Comment: +1 for providing info to back up your question (jsPerf). It's also a good question!

Comment: It's definitely implementation dependent, you can see that Chrome does not show such a behaviour.

Comment: I wouldn't ignore the fact that the test-environment itself may influence this results also. Might be reasonable to create another test-case on clean js file only.

Comment: I wonder if there is an optimization to bring non shadowed global variables into the current scope of a function. That would explain why the cached `n1` is slower.

Comment: Interesting... it's remarkable just how fast add1 performs there, way past Chrome. But that doesn't explain why add3 is slower than add2, when the variable is nearer scope wise.

Comment: It is important to mention that comparing Firefox with Chrome (I have tested on both), functions `add2` and `add3` performance is identical, while `add1` is **extremely faster** in Firefox, but in Chrome it performs in the same speed as `add2`. So, `add2` is much slower in Firefox because `add1` is superfast. In Chrome, both `add1` and `add2` speeds are the same as Firefox's `add2` speed.

Comment: @jAndy: add1: 3014ms, add2: 3096ms, add3: 3153ms

Comment: @robC: see my answer. Please try with the script I provided. In my results, it looks like jsPerf itself is to blame for those results.

Comment: @user1600680 your astute comment above appears to be the answer. I can't find any documentation of the optimization but a new test with no global scope exhibits the expected behaviour: http://jsperf.com/variable-scope-speed/7

Comment: Interesting. Yeah, I don't know if they every really document too many optimizations since I'd imagine they're always adding and improving them. Ultimately I'd just code for what seems to makes sense. Code written for a particular optimization in a particular browser can become obsolete in the next browser version.

Comment: Don't think I can accept a comment as the answer so you'll need to create that if you want to :)

Answer (score 2):

Its interesting, but my little testing here seems to confirm my earlier assumption, that is, the *jsPerf* environment influences scopes and scope-chain look-ups itself. I didn't digg into  the "how" and "why", but this is my little testscript:

```
var n1 = 12;

var add1 = function(n2){
        return n1 + n2;
}

var add2 = (function(){
        return function(n2){
                return n1 + n2;
        }
})();

var add3 = (function(){
        var cn1 = n1;
        return function(n2){
                return cn1 + n2;
        }
})();

var add4 = function( n2, n1 ) {
    return n2 + n1;
}.bind(null, n1);


var tests = [add1, add2, add3, add4],
    start, stop, loops;

tests.forEach(function( fnc ) {
    loops = 100000;

    start = Date.now();
    while( loops-- ) {
        fnc( 2 );
    }
    stop = Date.now();

    console.info('Method ', fnc.name || fnc.toString(), ': ', stop - start, ' ms.');
});
```

And the results on my FireFox 14 look like so:

> Method add1: 570ms.
>   Method add2: 566ms.
>   Method add3: 414ms.
>   Method add4: 479ms.

Latest Chrome results:

> Method add1: 199ms.
>   Method add2: 136ms.
>   Method add3: 85ms.
>   Method add4: 144ms.

Which definately looks more reasonable. A closured scope-chain lookup has to be always faster, simply for the fact that there is a shorter lookup-chain. Even if all modern browsers don't normally do a *classic* scope chain lookup, I'm aware of that. Anyway, since browsers create pretty clever lookup tables for free (or out-of-scope) variables, all results should at least be the same. It doesn't make any sense to over-optimize the global object access IMO.

As you noticed, I created one additional test-case for a bound method.

Comment: @J.Bruni: added. Same result, the closured scope access wins in an "real" independent env.

Comment: `Method function (n2) { return n1 + n2; } : 27ms.`
`Method function (n2) { return n1 + n2; } :24ms.`
`Method function (n2) { return cn1 + n2; } :39ms.`
`Method function () { [native code] } :59ms.`

Comment: @jAndy - here's my results from your script. How come yours took so long for only 100,000 loops?

Comment: @robC: I guess its pretty much depends on browser + hardware right? :). Which browser are you actually using ?

Comment: Firefox 14.0.1 on Windows 7. I want your theory to be true ;) but my JS console test bears out the jsperf result over 10000000 iterations: add1: 22ms, add2: 47ms, add3: 76ms. I just tested again in firebug and the numbers are much higher but the same trend: add1: 2887ms, add2: 2913ms, add3: 3099ms. Over many repeats I got one or two where the results were a lot flatter, am discounting them as environment.

Comment: @robC: actually, its not a theory, its the spec. So, that should be very true. Did you put my testscript in an empty `.js` file and call let it run entirely without anything else (like jsPerf) ?

Comment: Well, I put your script into a script tag in the body of an empty html page, and ran it both in the firefox console and firebug. I also ran my own script which is similar. It isn't 'the spec' that jsperf is erroneously altering the result, which is your theory. Thanks a lot for testing though :)

Comment: well, with "the spec", I meant how ECMAscript and lexical scope works in theory (and practice actually).

Comment: To confirm on this, jsPerf was not to blame.

Answer (score 0):

```
var n1 = 12;

// "add1" is superfast in Firefox, but not in Chrome. Why?
// it seems Firefox is smarter in retrieving n1 value from global scope
var add1 = function(n2){
        return n1 + n2;
}

// "add2" is much slower in Firefox, but in Chrome the speed is almost equal to "add2"
// it seems that Firefox's smart retrieving from global scope is not applied in this case
// it is understandable that "add2" is slower, because the interpreter needs to go back two levels in the scope chain to find the "n1" variable value
var add2 = (function(){
        return function(n2){
                return n1 + n2;
        }
})();

// If JavaScript works as PHP, then it won't copy "n1" value in "cn1".
// If this is the case, then it is understandle why it is slower.
// The interpreter first needs to search and find "cn1" value;
// when it finally finds it in the previous scope level,
// then it needs to start a second "search and find travel", looking for the value.
// This means "cn1" does not contain "12", but a reference to it in the memory.
// While I don't know if this is how JavaScript engine works,
// I know that PHP does not create a copy of the value -
// both variables share the same content in the memory.
// Short story being: it is slower because it must perform two "searches" instead of one.
var add3 = (function(){
        var cn1 = n1;
        return function(n2){
                return cn1 + n2;
        }
})();
```

Comment: JavaScript isn't like PHP in that way. It does copy the value, so when `cn1` is found, it doesn't need to go any further. If you change the value of `n1`, the `cn1` variable will not observe the change.

Comment: In PHP is the same: "If you change the value of `n1`, the `cn1` variable will not observe the change." But in PHP **until** you change the value, there is a single value stored in the memory, shared by both variables. It saves memory. This is called "COW" - Copy-On-Write... see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260296/php-null-and-copy-on-write

Comment: Interesting. I don't know PHP. But mainly I'm saying that once `cn1` is found, it does not search for `n1`. No COW in JavaScript. :)